# Replace similar words in a string

Tags: javascript, text, replace

I have these strings:

```
var a = ".-. - --. .. - . .-. .. .";
var x = "";
```

I want to replace:

```
".-." with "r"
"-" with "t"
"--." with "g"
".." with "i"
"." with "e"
```

and store the value on the variable x, so the new string should become:

```
x = "r t g i t e r i e";
```

I have tried with this but doesn't work:

```
var a = ".-. - --. .. - . .-. .. .";
var x = "";

//first of all, words with 3 characters
x = a.replace(/.-./g, "r");
x = x.replace(/--./g, "g");

//then words with 2 characters
x = x.replace(/../g, "i");

//finally words with 1 character
x = x.replace(/-/g, "t");
x = x.replace(/./g, "e");
document.write(x);
```

x becomes "eeeeeeee" why? How to fix?
Thank you everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `.` in the regular expressions  like `\.`

```
var a = ".-. - --. .. - . .-. .. .";
var x = "";

//first of all, words with 3 characters
x = a.replace(/\.-\./g, "r");
console.log(x);
x = x.replace(/--./g, "g");
console.log(x);

//then words with 2 characters
x = x.replace(/\.\./g, "i");
console.log(x);

//finally words with 1 character
x = x.replace(/-/g, "t");
console.log(x);
x = x.replace(/\./g, "e");
console.log(x);
document.write(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

`.` in a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions) matches any character (except some special characters).

To specifically match the `.` character, use `\.`, for example:

```
x = x.replace(/\./g, "e");
```